# String date to java.sql.Date

Tags: java, mysql, date

I have a date with the format as                                                                              **Fri Nov 16 00:00:00 CXT 2012**

And I want to store in Mysql database using my java program.

Im writing the following code

```
    SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
    java.util.Date date = sdf1.parse(split[4]);
    java.sql.Date sqlStartDate = new java.sql.Date(date.getTime());
```

But it throws this error Exception in thread "main" java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Fri Nov 16 00:00:00 CXT 2012"

How to do it. ?

Comment: Obviously, you have to start coding. Hint : SimpleDateFormat class in java.

Comment: Where's your problem? Formatting/parsing the date? Writing to the database? What have you tried already?

Comment: Hi thomas , I have edited my post with code and error

Comment: so why do you think that `Fri Nov 16 00:00:00 ` will parse as `dd-MM-yyyy` ?

Comment: The format you provided obviously doesn't match the date, as Scary Wombat already said. You'd need to change the format to include the day-of-week, the month name in abreviated form, the time as well as the time zone and the year moved to the end of the date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is exactly whay you need:

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss z yyyy");
        Date parsed = format.parse("Fri Nov 16 00:00:00 CXT 2012");
        java.sql.Date sql = new java.sql.Date(parsed.getTime());
    }
}
```

Comment: Glad it helped. Please accept the answer since it solved your problem.